# which android folder to resource of night mode, v21+? drawable-night-v21?

Tags: android, resources, android-drawable, android-night-mode

I know I can add resources for some Android versions + for night mode.

But what would be the name of the folder for night mode resources of API 21+ ?

`drawable-night-v21`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be correct. Based on [the legendary "Table 2"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=en#AlternativeResources):

- `night` is the qualifier for night mode
- `v21` is the qualifier for API Level 21+ devices
- `night` appears higher in Table 2 than does `v21`, so `night` appears first in the directory name

So, `-night-v21` would be the suffix for any resource directory in which you will have night mode resources to be used on API Level 21+ devices.

Comment: Should we add the v21 though? From which version is it supported as more than just car and/or dock mode weird case ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Should we add the v21 though?" -- the asker of the question wanted it, so I rolled with it. :-) "From which version is it supported as more than just car and/or dock mode weird case ?" -- I would not expect night mode to be tied to docks (there are other qualifiers for those). `-night` has been around since API Level 8. However, I never did much research into its behavior, in large part because the trigger mechanism was murky.

Comment: Maybe the support library allows using it from API 21 , manually, and on Android Q it's also possible to do it automatically? But then, why add the v21 qualifier... It's not like it could hurt before, no? Odd...